# Why does my bash script hang when sending mail with option -s?

Tags: bash, email

I have tried to send mail from command line:

```
echo "hello world" | mail myname@somewhere.com
```

all works.
But when I try add subject like:

```
echo "hello world" | mail -s "some subject" myname@somewhere.com
```

all hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works OK for me on : SunOS host 5.8 Generic_117350-61 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440

**EDIT :** Just a thought, have you closed all of your quoted strings?